# How to unwrap an observable inside behavioursubject .next() in rx Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

This is the way of creating and using a behaviour subject.

```
// component/class 1


item = new BehaviourSubject(null)
item$ 

constructor() {
    this.item$  = this.item.asObservable()

/// and to get value from item$ we do

this.item$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
}
```

Now to pass another value to a behaviour subject or to trigger changes we do the following:

```
// component/class 2


someObservable$.subscribe(value => {
    this.item.next(value)
}
)
```

So my question is that is there a way to pass the above value without subscribing to `someObservable$`?

Something like this:

Such that the observable unwraps itself inside the behaviour subject.

```
this.item.next(someObservable$)

// when I does this the item$ observable returns an observable wrapped inside another observable and not a real value.
```

Comment: An observable doesn't have a value. You have to subscribe to register an observer.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But since I'm creating an observable from the behaviour subject and subscribing to it like this: ```this.item$  = this.item.asObservable()```. I hope this to work ```this.item.next(someObservable$)```

Comment: Isn't it not possible for you to subscribe to someObjservable$ in the required component, if you can subscribe to item$?

Comment: `this.item.next` sets a value. Therefore the value has to exist. An observable doesn't have value. You have to register an observer and wait for a value.

Comment: Yes. But the problem is that these two observables are in separate components. For the sake of simplicity I did the above one.

Comment: usually u return it in a function like `getItem() { return this.item.asObjservable(); }`. and in the required component, you do, `this.<service>.getItem().subscribe(value => value);`

Comment: Actually, the observable ```someObservable$``` is from another component which sets value through  ```.next()```.

Comment: this doesn't serves the purpose of rxjs.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to rxjs. This doesn't work with the [observer design pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Why not? This should be possible right. If my intuition is correct.

But since I'm creating an observable from the behaviour subject and subscribing to it like this: ```this.item$  = this.item.asObservable()```. I hope this to work ```this.item.next(someObservable$)```

Comment: There should be a way of doing this. The how are we supposed to pass a next value from an observable to a behaviour subject?

Comment: Is there a clean way of passing a data from an observable to a behaviour subject?

Comment: There is no data in an observable. You have to register an observer. You should read the [overview](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observer) in rxjs. That could help.

Comment: Where are you subscribing for item$? Does this component need the latest of both observables? If thats the case, you could instead subscribe for both using `forkjoin`. `forkJoin({
      item: item$,
      someObs: someObs$
    })
    .subscribe(({item, someObjs}) => { console.log(item, someObjs  });` So you dont have to worry when you will have both the data. As forkjoin will run once it gets both values.

Comment: "*how are we supposed to pass a next value from an observable to a behavior subject?*" What is your intention?  I think perhaps you are asking the wrong question.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the answer is simply "no". An observable doesn't contain a value. Therefore you can't read the value of an observable and use it in a function call like `this.item.next(observable$)`. You have to subscribe an observer.

Of course you could use a behavior subject instead. A behavior subject contains a current value.

```
this.item.next(behaviorSubject$.value)
```

is possible.